# Is there a way to clear password mid-entry?

Tags: command-line

I understand that a standard terminal security feature is to not show '*'s or indicate any kind of progress of password input. If I know that I have typed a password wrong, rather than having to hit enter and wait for the form to ask me again, is there a way to remove all hidden input?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `bash`, following will clear your input before the cursor: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

Same applies for passwords, i.e.: *my-wrong-password* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> *my-good-password*

Comment: Working perfectly, will mark as correct in 5 minutes when I'm allowed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I always mash like 100 times on backspace and it seems to work for me.
And re-enter my password

Comment: Hey Dr Bunsen, just tried that, not working for me..?

Comment: try Ctrl + U
and backspace also works on 12.04, m8 of mine just checked

Comment: Yep that's working for me, marked Andrejs Cainikovs' answer as correct.

Comment: ok ;) good to hear thats its working for you. what Ubuntu version are you running?!

Comment: I'm also on 12.04.